# Pulsometer that can export pulse vs time information

Tags: running, tracking

I want to train high intensity interval in running and would like to buy a pulsometer that can export later pulse recording to the computer (preferably in mac os x), do you know any?

Comment: I think this [Timex model](http://astore.amazon.com/howtogetbackinshape-20/detail/B001JBU6YY?) will do what you want **if** you have a Mac OS 10.6 or higher.  The reason I like Timex over Polar is that I can change the battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pulsmeter market is very big with a few global brands (Polar, Garmin, Suunto) and lots of local brands. I have been using Suunto for 5 years now, both a "R to R" recording belt and a watch for feeback during the actual practise.

If you are about to buy one, here are some simple checks regarding service and maintenace:

1. Check their service agreement, sometimes things break down (this happens to all manufacturers based on discussions at e.g. Funbeat and other training forums) and the guarantee and replacement service is important. My experience from Suunto is that there are no questions asked, almost overnight replacement and very helpful customer service. Others that have Polar etc have similar experiences.
2. Check how open they are (e.g. support for ANT+) and support for exporting measurement data from client/web software. Garmin supports ANT+ (they even bought the company behind the standard).
3. Check how easy it is for simpler do it yourself maintenance, e.g. change batteries. No problems with Suunto.

Regarding features, the "go to" site is DC rainmaker, see [DC R blog](http://www.dcrainmaker.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the Polar line of Heart Rate monitors.  They have been in the business for longer than most.  There are several higher end models with computer interfaces that can download data.

Failing that, many of the new running watches that have GPS allow computer connections to download and some of them now come with HRM straps, so I imagine it should be possible.  (Like the Garmin Forerunner series).

There is some really cool watch technology out there!